# Google-Maps-iOS-Utils with google maps missing GMSGeometryUtils.h

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods, markerclusterer

I been struguling with this for hours now, I can't understand what is wrong. I followed googles iOS cluster setup carefully, but no mater what I do it doesn't work. I'm getting this error:

**.../Pods/Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/src/Clustering/Algo/GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.m:22:9: 'GoogleMaps/GMSGeometryUtils.h' file not found**

I have installed the following:

```
Using Alamofire (3.4.1)
Using Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (1.0.0)
Using GoogleMaps (1.9.2)
```

Pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.3'
use_frameworks!

pre_install do |installer|
        def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies; end
    end
target 'Happevents' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps' # Objective-C pod
    pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' # Objective-C pod
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4' # Swift pod
end
```

Comment: One thing I found out is that it's swift relevant problem, if I remove use_frameworks! and Alamofire then error dissapiers.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Google-Maps-iOS-Utils in my project by pod installation. Please update your pod file

```
target 'Happevents' do
pod 'GoogleMaps' # Objective-C pod
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', :git => 'https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4' # Swift pod
```

end

Comment: It gives an error: [!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: Alamofire

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `use_frameworks!` from your pod file

Answer (score 0):

[There is a manual](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md) from Google how to use their library with Swift and use_frameworks! you could also [check this one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/setup#create-a-bridging-header-swift-only).